# plink - Password change required but no TTY available

Tags: passwords, cmd.exe, putty, tty, plink

I have 1000 servers to work with, but today all the server passwords expired. 
I regularly use plink (PuTTY) to connect with 1000 servers.  Today I got error “Password change required but no TTY available”.

Then I have enabled TTY by enabling `plink -ssh -t` and tried to attempt to change password with below command

```
m:\plink>echo.password1 & echo.password2 & echo.password2 | plink -ssh -t username@13NB:xx0:320:112:0:0:0:XY -pw password1
```

but passwd: Authentication token manipulation error occured.

While doing manually (human inputs on Windows-cli) everything works fine, but while doing automatically something went wrong.

When attempting another method:

```
m:\plink>plink -ssh -t username@13NB:xx0:320:112:0:0:0:XY -pw password1 < credential.txt
```

credential.txt contains 3 lines: password1 password2 password2

but till password1 (current unix password) it is success after that the command unable to take password 2 and prompting newpassword.

Please provide a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CMD is interpreting your command line as

```
m:\plink>echo.password1
m:\plink>echo.password2
m:\plink>echo.password2 | plink …
```

To get all three passwords sent to the pipe, you need to group the `echo` commands:

```
m:\plink>(echo.password1 & echo.password2 & echo.password2) | plink …
```

Comment: i have tried the above with closed brackets.. but still same issue.. passwd: Authentication token manipulation error occured